# Module has no Attribute: Calling a second function

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

I'm trying to use module to call functions I want to use. My setup is similar to the one below:

passObject.py

```
def addTwoNumber(a,b):
    c = a + b
    return c

def multiplyTwoNumbers(a,b):
    c = a * b
    return c
```

importObject.py

```
import passObject

a = passObject.addTwoNumber(1,3)
print a


b = passObject.multiplyTwoNumbers(a,4)
print b
```

My result for this is complaining that there is no such attribute. Yet it is able to call the first function but not the second. In Python's doc's example for module's it gives an example of two functions being used so it would seem that is totally legit. I'm pretty lost  here.

```
>>> execfile('importObject.py')
4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "importObject.py", line 8, in <module>
    b = passObject.multiplyTwoNumbers(a,4)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'multiplyTwoNumbers'
```

Comment: Why is one "Number" and the other "Numbers"?

Comment: Lol. No reason at all.  I guess I got lazy when I wrote that first one. I wrote it quickly as the the code I was really working on was a bit to long to paste here.

Comment: The above code looks right to me. Check for typos and indentation problems.

Comment: Ok. So I reran this from outside the python command line as seen above and everything worked just fine. Is this an issue with execfile() or running directly from the interpreter? Idk but it sounds over my head. Edit: No I restarted my python command line and everything works just fine. I still don't know what would cause that. But it fixed my issue on my actual code too.